# Google OAuth in an iOS Home Screen web app: fullscreen apps blocked?

Tags: ios, google-oauth

We're observing the following behavior with the Google OAuth change:

- Webapps accessed via Safari in iOS 9+ can do a Google OAuth flow, same as ever.
- Webapps saved to the home screen can also do the usual flow
- Webapps saved to the home screen that have the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta attribute do NOT -- they are blocked via the "disallowed user agent" error.

It seems that apps saved to the home screen that have the fullscreen meta tag report their user agent as `Web/1.0 CFNetwork/758.5.3 Darwin/15.6.0`, which is different than MobileSafari (it is also different than the user agent in an embedded UIWebView).

This is a bit of a bind, since enabling the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` mode is the only way to do a few other things, such as autoplay audio, which we use to teach the kids math!

Anyone have ideas on a path out of this double-bind? Alternatives we can think of include:

- Find a way for Google to distinguish fullscreen homepage webapps from embedded WKWebViews. (UPDATE: based on the user agents above, they can be distinguished. But Google may still want to block them.)
- Coax Google to allow this user agent. Unfortunately, I think there is a rationale for blocking OAuth on fullscreen webapps -- without a location bar, the user can't verify they've been sent to a legitimate Google login page.
- Coax Apple to report fullscreen webapps as MobileSafari rather than this user agent. (??doubtful)
- Build a native or Cordova version of the whole app, just to work around this one issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've been doing some reading and thinking, and can imagine a rationale for why Google could want to block OAuth for these fullscreen web clip apps -- since the user can't see a web location bar, they can't be 100% certain they've actually been redirected to accounts.google.com, and not something malicious that looks like it. Updated the question to reflect this.